# New to ubuntu and asking for advice

Tags: 19.10

the files on my dev/sda1,2,3 are read-only. I cannot copy files into it or remove files from it or do any actions to anything not even creat folders, I run from my Administrator account and I open properties to find it read and write but when I do any action it say there is no permission read only file > I am new to ubuntu system so I don really know If this issue cause of installing or I should do some command to unlock all my files ( notice that I can create folder save files and do anything just fine at /home )

Comment: You say that you can save folders and files on your home directory? Then everything is fine. Linux will not allow you as normal user to create ANY files outside your home directory.  You can do it as root in terminal - but that is not recommended.

Comment: Apparently `/dev/sda1`, 2 and 3 are not the partition that you installed Ubuntu on, and `/home` isn't on them either. What kind of partitions are they, and more important, how are they mounted? Enter the command `mount` into a terminal, and dig out the lines that describe `/dev/sda1`-`3`. Then, edit your question and add those lines.

Comment: If you are new to Ubuntu then you shouldn't be accessing anything in /dev directly. These are parts of the inner workings of Ubuntu and you can easily break your system by messing with them. Also you shouldn't run anything as `root` (which I guess is what you meant by "Administrator account".) Work as a regular user and when the commands you run from the menu require administrator privileges they'll ask for your password.